# ReferenceError: split is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The function `Lastrows2` works properly. However, the Convert_txt_gsheets throws

> ReferenceError: split is not defined

which terminates the whole thing, and stops lastrow2 from ever engaging. Splits confuse me immensely.

```
function pricing() {
  convert_txt_gsheets();
  lastrow2();
}

function convert_txt_gsheets() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Daily Report');
  var targetrange = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());
  targetrange.clear();

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID2');
  var body = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split(/\r/);
  var result = body.map(split(/|/))
    // vvv
    .map(row => row.map(cell => cell.replaceAll(`"`, ``)));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily Report').getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
  return;
}



function lastrow2() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Daily Report');
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Permanent Record');
var target = target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());
var rangeValues = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn()).getValues();
target.setValues(rangeValues); 
}
```

This is the example data that is being pulled from txt.

```
COLUMN0|COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|COLUMN5|COLUMN6|COLUMN7|COLUMN8  
"Rocketship"|"5.99"|"5.39"|"5.39"|""|"5.39"|"5.39"|"7.5.2022"|"william"
```

MODIFIED CODE

```
function pricing() {
  convert_txt_gsheets();
  lastrow2();
}

function convert_txt_gsheets() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Daily Report');
  var targetrange = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());
  targetrange.clear();

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID2');
let body = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split('\r'); //  split into rows
let results = body.map( row => row.split('|') ); // split into columns
results = result.map( col => col.map( cell => cell.replaceAll(`"`, ``)));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily Report').getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
  return;
}



function lastrow2() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Daily Report');
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Permanent Record');
var target = target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());
var rangeValues = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn()).getValues();
target.setValues(rangeValues); 
}
```

Comment: Map accepts a function: `body.map(row => row.split(/|/))`

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in `var result = body.map(split(/|/))`.  Try this.

Replace:

```
var body = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split(/\r/);
var result = body.map(split(/|/))
// vvv
  .map(row => row.map(cell => cell.replaceAll(`"`, ``)));
```

This is my test set.  Replace the lines above as appropriate.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let data = 'COLUMN0|COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|COLUMN5|COLUMN6|COLUMN7|COLUMN8\r "Rocketship"|"5.99"|"5.39"|"5.39"|""|"5.39"|"5.39"|"7.5.2022"|"william"';
    let body = data.split('\r'); //  split into rows
    let results = body.map( row => row.split('|') ); // split into columns
    results = results.map( col => col.map( cell => cell.replaceAll(`"`, ``) ) );
    console.log(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

I'm not sure about the date but the others will be converted to their appropriate type when you setValues().

```
6:59:01 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:59:04 AM  Info    [ [ 'COLUMN0', 'COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2', 'COLUMN3', 'COLUMN4', 'COLUMN5', 'COLUMN6', 'COLUMN7', 'COLUMN8' ],
  [ ' Rocketship', '5.99', '5.39', '5.39', '', '5.39', '5.39',  '7.5.2022', 'william' ] ]
6:59:02 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Apologies. Could you tell me where I should put that in my code to make it work? I'm really a beginner, I struggled with my code as it is

Comment: I modified the code, some )); were missing in the last lines of yours I added them. Now I'm receiving Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. Any ideas? I updated the OP with the current code

Comment: Typo `results` not `result`

Comment: I made the adjustment Same Exception

Comment: I've include my complet test script.