# Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. Issue with the code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, exception

I'm having issues with the below code, the error I receive is specifically

> Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.

The purpose of the script is as follows. The are two files located in the google drive, one Pipe pipe delimited txt, and a google spreadsheet. The script is supposed to pull the date from the txt, put it into the spreadsheet-sheet1, and then copy it over to an archive on sheet2. I receive the above error. I'd appreciate a clear solution as I'm very much a rookie.

```
function pricing() {
  convert_txt_gsheets();
  lastrow2();
}

function convert_txt_gsheets() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Daily Report');
  var targetrange = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());
  targetrange.clear();

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID2');
let body = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split('\r'); //  
let results = body.map( row => row.split('|') ); // split into columns
    results = results.map( col => col.map( cell => cell.replaceAll(`"`, ``) ) );
    console.log(results);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily Report').getRange(1, 1, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results);
  return;
}



function lastrow2() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Daily Report');
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Permanent Record');
var target = target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());
var rangeValues = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn()).getValues();
target.setValues(rangeValues); 
}
```

Example of the TXT Data:

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4 | COLUMN5 | COLUMN6 | COLUMN7 | Date | COLUMN9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Item" | "5.99" | "5.39" | "5.39" | "" | "5.39" | "5.39" | "7.7.2022" | "Wobble" |
| "Lime" | "3.99" | "3.49" | "3.49" | "" | "3.49" | "3.49" | "7.7.2022" | "Dobble" |
| "House" | "17.69" | "16.99" | "16.99" | "" | "16.99" | "16.99" | "7.7.2022" | "Wobble" |
| "Door" | "7.99" | "8.99" | "7.99" | "" | "7.99" | "7.99" | "7.7.2022" | "Dobble" |

Comment: You didn't correct the typo `result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)` should be `results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results)`  See your previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886740/referenceerror-split-is-not-defined-im-useless-with-concept-of-split/72887055?noredirect=1#comment128775957_72887055

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: split is not defined - Im useless with concept of split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886740/referenceerror-split-is-not-defined-im-useless-with-concept-of-split)

Comment: @TheWizEd I have made the modification. Still same issue Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.

Comment: `console.log(results);` does this show what results looks like?  Are you sure `convert_txt_gsheets` is the one causing the error?

Comment: @TheWizEd Yes, its definitely gsheets that throws the error. I tried both functions separately lastrow2 does not cause any issues

Comment: In gsheets: `var targetrange = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());` source contains data?  Can `source.getLastRow()` be 0?

Comment: @TheWizEd I tried replacing source.getLastRow() with 0 the same error. The data is exactly the same format as the example. just many more rows

Comment: No you misunderstood.  If there is no data in `source` then `getLastRow()` is 0 and that can be causing the error.

Comment: @TheWizEd That definitely did something. I added data to the sheet, so that getLastrow has something to work with, and that seems to have somewhat fixed things? As in, the data is now being pulled from the txt. However, the exception is still there Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 9. Which leads to a failure and the second function never engaging.

Comment: I believe there is a blank row in your data, most likely the last, which results in an unsymmetrical array.  All rows are arrays of 9 values and the the blank row is an array of 1 value.

Comment: @TheWizEd If that is the case, how could I go about fixing it?

Comment: You need to examine the file you're parsing.  I can't do that.  Maybe that's not the problem.  If you can view with a text editor see how many lines there are and if any are blank or there is an extra line at the end.

Comment: @TheWizEd I went through the original file. Some items don't have any data in the columns. But, that shouldn't be an issue. There is one additional blank line at the end.